# UI Design: Popular Site Layout Grid Systems > 960

Tags: css, html, layout, user-interface

I am familiar with the popular [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/) setup and it's been very helpful - but I am looking for other popular/heavily-adopted solutions with the following abilities:

- Larger base resolution (1280px rather than 1024px)?
- Makes use of HTML5 semantic layout tags: `ASIDE`, `NAV`, etc.
- Clean CSS: few "tricks/quirks" as possible... CSS3 would be a bonus.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if many people are still using the 960px layout since many people are into responsive design now. Check out [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), tutorial from [tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using/)(html5/css3 starter), [cssgrid](http://cssgrid.net/), [fluid base grid](http://fluidbaselinegrid.com/)(targets any resolution). Not sure if those helped but should give you an idea. I would go with fluid or used one of these as a boilerplate for new projects.

Answer (score 2):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) features a grid system as well. It is kind of based on the 960 one but you can also modify it to roll your own. And it has a bunch of other shiny features (including HTML 5 and CSS 3).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It looks pretty thick with features, a little too think honestly - I have no need for the pre-made controls, buttons, stylized tags... just want a clean layout system that works with HTML5 semantic tags. Also, I didn't see Bootstrap making much use of HTML5, just more DIVs and SPANs everywhere. Anything lighterweight?

Comment: You can always use the CSS only. And no matter what Grid system you choose, it is just a grid system. Tt totally doesn't care if you apply it to HTML 5 elements or divs.

Comment: sure it does matter, if the CSS styles are designed to work for specific classes and id containers they are designed for elements that already possess certain properties. I'm still a noob with HTML5 but a `HEADER` or `ASIDE` container is different from a `DIV` or `SPAN` the style classes might product different/unpredictable results, right?

Comment: Not really for the grids because they can be applied as a class to any element, e.g. the 960 grid uses things like `.container_12 .grid_4` as the selector. These HTML 5 elements make a semantic difference, but it doesn't matter for CSS styling because they are just displayed as block elements like any div.